# Make 2 divs responsive but still on mobile they are jump up

Tags: html, css

***Edit***
upload the imegs to show the problem, flex-wrap dont solve it still jump on mobile..

on web

```
https://ibb.co/HKwsfFT 
https://ibb.co/ck3wYtF
```

on mobile

```
https://ibb.co/b5GgRZr
https://ibb.co/QJv5gF3
```

any more suggestion ?

***End Edit***

I am trying to make 2 div's inside a box responsive on mobile.

In my browser's developer tools everything seems good in every mobile screen resolution, but when I access the site from real mobile the 2 dive's with the boxes jump up to something like 10-20 px and not stay in place.
 just wanna them a little bit down of the bar of 'woodwork' and for the next little bit lower than they not collide... 
thx for any help.
(sorry for the messy code lol)

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  overflow: scroll;
  margin: 5;
}

#topcase {
  background-color: #f3e0be;
  height: 1050px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: baseline;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

.middlecase {
  background-image: url("../img/hdback.jpg");
  height: 100px;
  width: 100.8%;
  top: 95px;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: baseline;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0px -10px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.43), 0px 10px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.52);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 515px) {
  div.we-are0 {
    font-size: 35px;
    line-height: 1;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 514px) {
  div.we-are0 {
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 1;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 275px) {
  div.we-are0 {
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1;
  }
}

.we-are0 {
  color: #FEE5A4;
  position: absolute;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 #84817a, 0 1px #84817a, 1px 0 #84817a, 0 -1px #84817a;
  letter-spacing: 2;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 501px) {
  header.who-are-we {
    font-size: 17px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  header.who-are-we {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  header.who-are-we {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  header.who-are-we {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 250px) {
  header.who-are-we {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 200px) {
  header.who-are-we {
    font-size: 11px;
  }
}

.who-are-we {
  top: 27rem;
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  letter-spacing: 1;
  text-align: center;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(-5%, -50%);
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #f7e8bb;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -10px 0px 13px -7px #000000, 10px 0px 13px -7px #000000, 5px 5px 15px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  box-shadow: -10px 0px 13px -7px #000000, 10px 0px 13px -7px #000000, 5px 5px 15px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 501px) {
  header.what-we-do {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  header.what-we-do {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  header.what-we-do {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  header.what-we-do {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 250px) {
  header.what-we-do {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 200px) {
  header.what-we-do {
    font-size: 11px;
  }
}

.what-we-do {
  top: 50rem;
  position: absolute;
  letter-spacing: 1;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(-5%, -50%);
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #f7e8bb;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -10px 0px 13px -7px #000000, 10px 0px 13px -7px #000000, 5px 5px 15px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  box-shadow: -10px 0px 13px -7px #000000, 10px 0px 13px -7px #000000, 5px 5px 15px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header id="topcase">
    <div class="lg" id="lg">
      <a href="index.html">
        <img src="../img/logo.png" class="logo" id="logo" alt="LOGO" style="vertical-align:top">
      </a>
    </div>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Wood-Work-%D7%AA%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%95%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%A2-%D7%93%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%92%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A0%D7%92%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%95%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A2%D7%A5-102057181481598/"
      class="facebook"></a>
    <div class="btn">
      <a href="tel:+972508187780" class="btn effect04" data-sm-link-text="050-818-7780" target="_blank"><span>050-818-7780</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="gr">
      <a href="#section2" class="to-glr">
        לגלריה
        <br />
        שלנו
      </a>
    </div>
    <a class="top-link hide" href="#topcase" id="js-top">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 12 6">
        <path d="M12 6H0l6-6z" /></svg>
      <span class="screen-reader-text">Back to top</span>
    </a>
    <a class="fb" href="https://www.facebook.com/Wood-Work-%D7%AA%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%95%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%A2-%D7%93%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%92%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A0%D7%92%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%95%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A2%D7%A5-102057181481598/">
      <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Wood-Work-%D7%AA%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%95%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%A2-%D7%93%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%92%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A0%D7%92%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%95%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A2%D7%A5-102057181481598/"
        class="fab fa-facebook-"></a>
  </header>
  <header id="middlecase" class="middlecase">
    <div class="we-are0" id="we-are0">
      <p>
        Wood Work
      </p>
      <p>
        תכנון ובניה בעץ וברזל בעיצוב אישי
      </p>
    </div>
  </header>
  <header id="showcase">
    <header id="who-are-we" class="who-are-we">
      <div class="we-are1">
        <p>
          Wood Work אנחנו בחברת
        </p>
        <p>
          ,מתמחים בעבודה ,בעץ ברזל ועיצוב הגינה
        </P>
        <p>
          החל מהתיכנון ועד הביצוע על ידי שימוש בחומרים המובילים בשוק
        </p>
        <p>
        </p>
        ולצד הקולגות ואנשי המקצוע
        <a class="the-most">
          הכי
        </a> המובילים בעולם הבניה
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="we-are2">
        <p>
          אנו מייצרים ומתקינים עבודות עץ מורכבות
        </p>
        ,בשילוב אלמנטים נסתרים
        <p>
          !על מנת לקבל מראה נקי ומקסימום בטיחות
        </p>
        <br />
      </div>
      <div class="we-are3">
        <P>
          :אנו משלבים כמה טכניקות בניה כמו
        </P>
        <P>
          בניה קונבציונלית
        </P>
        <p>
          בניה קלה
        </P>
        <p>
          Timber Frame-וסגנון ה
        </P>
        <p>
          (השיטה המסורתית של מחברי עץ ללא ברגים)
        </p>
        <p>
          על מנת לייעל וליצור מראה נקי דקורטיבי וחזק
        </p>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="we-are-4">
        <p>
          אתם צריכים רק לדמיין מה תרצו להוסיף או לחדש
        </p>
        <P>
          ,ואנחנו נדאג לביצוע ברמה הגבוהה ביותר
        </P>
        <div>
          <P>
            ליווי צמוד מקצועי ואדיב לאורך כל הדרך
          </P>
          <p>
            עד לגמר העבודה
          </p>
        </div>
    </header>
    <header class="what-we-do" id="what-we-do">
      <div>
        <P>
          ** דקים מכל הסוגים והדקורציות **
        </P>
        <P>
          ** פרגולות מורכבות ומעוצבות **
        </P>
        <P>** גדרות ושערים ** </P>
        <P>** חיפוי קירות במניפה רחבה של אפשרויות ** </P>
        <P>** חיפוי בריכות אינטקס **
        </P>
        <P>** גגונים ומרזבים **
        </P>
        <P>** הקמת ותחזוקת גינות ופינות ירק ונוי **
        </P>
        <P>** גינון כללי **
        </P>
        <p>** בתי עץ **
        </p>
        <p>** תוספת בניה **
        </p>
        <p>** רהיטי גן **
        </p>
        <p>** הנחת דשא סינטטי **
        </p>
        <P>** חידוש דקים גדרות ופרגולות **
        </P>
        <P>** בכל הגוונים והצבעים **
        </P>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `display:flex`.

You give the outside div `display:flex` and `flex-wrap:nowrap`.

You can solve this.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap. please check here

Comment: ye alrdy know it, but its not solve my problem..
ill re explain: 
got 2 bit header (who-we-are, and what-we-do)
they lying on a nice 2 boxes on computer web, bet when get in from my phone the 2 boxex go little up and colide